# AMP-Email security

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

I am successfully sending forms with data from amp-email, but there is a security issue.
Can a hacker intercept the data that the user sends via the form in amp-email? If it can, what is the probability and how easy it is to do it.

Answer (score 0):

- Hacker can see your requests from email to backend API in chrome devTools.
- Example of expluatation:

Let's say that our site has a page showing the history of weather observations for a single city. The ID of this city is passed by the link in the request parameter: `/weather.php?city_id=<ID>`, where `ID` - is the primary key of the city.
In a PHP script, we use this parameter for substitutions in an SQL query:

```
$city_id = $_GET['city_id'];
$res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM weather_log WHERE city_id = " . $city_id);
```

If the server passed the city_id parameter equal to 10 `/weather.php?city_id=10`, an SQL query is executed:

`SELECT * FROM weather_log WHERE city_id = 10`

But if the attacker passes the string `-1 OR 1=1` as the id parameter, the request is executed:

`SELECT * FROM weather_log WHERE city_id = -1 OR 1=1`

Adding SQL language constructs to the input parameters (instead of simple values) changes the execution logic of the entire SQL query!

In this example, instead of showing data for one city, data for all cities will be received, because the expression 1=1 is always true. Instead of the `SELECT ...` expression, there could be an expression for updating data, and then the consequences would be even more serious.

The lack of proper processing of SQL query parameters is one of the most serious vulnerabilities. Never insert data from the user in SQL queries "as is"!

Answer (score 0):

Although there are multiple touch points to the entire request cycle.
The one most in your control is your backend service

Here are some of my learning from building a few production ready and heavy usage AMP emails

1. Try using signed/pre-signed urls.
2. Try and handle most errors or exceptions at the backend. Writing a basic interface to pass your requests if you have multiple endpoints connected to your AMP email service is a great idea.
3. Try acknowledging amp events in your backend and keep the logic agnostic and within the authenticated cluster.
4. Try out some tests in your stag environments to validate the stuff you have before rolling to production. Creating a two way network proxy and playing around helped me understand the events and triggers really well, hence was able to design the systems with a better picture.